# ModelAndView forward

Tags: spring-mvc

The spring MVC ModelAndView forward is not working. The below code is not forwarding the request to Name.jsp. Your help much appreciated.

```
package main.java.com.mkyong.common.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class indexController {@RequestMapping(value= {"/index"})    
public ModelAndView forward() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView( "forward:/pages/Name.jsp");
    model.addObject("msg","Forward Handled");
    return model;

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView forward(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("msg","Forward Handled");

    return new ModelAndView("/pages/Name.jsp");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to replace the return type to be String and return "forward:/some/where/" , so, you request handler will look something like this:

```
package main.java.com.mkyong.common.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class indexController {@RequestMapping(value= {"/index"})    
public String forward() {
    model.addObject("msg","Forward Handled");
    return "forward:/some/where/to/go";

}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the accepted answer might not be correct depending your usecase.

To forward using ModelAndView (sometimes you can't return a String):

```
return new ModelAndView("forward:/error");
```